# String vector sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl-algorithm

I havent used sorting and alogorithms much and am Ok with vectors. Recently i faced an interesting question and want your suggestions with how to solve it. So, below is my question.

Q, I have been given 4 character strings in a vector and have to arrange those in a particular order depending on what those characters are. So, that the last character of any string should match with the first character of any other string and the last character of this string should be matched with the first character of any other string and this way i have to create a longest possible string.

For eg if i have a string vector like "ABCD" "TGHI" "DADC" "IYUR" "CXYT"
so it would be arrange like "ABCD"then there would be the third string"DADC" then there would be the fifth string"CXYT" and so on
So, the result will be "ABCD""DADC""CXYT""TGHI""IYUR".

Now,i was wondering if it would be a good idea to check each string with other string if it is 'compatible' according to the above rules.. so if i have 5 strings in the vector then i would have 5+4+3+2+1 possiblties and if for eg i have 20 strings then it would increase alot, so is this a good idea or is there any other good efficient solution to this...
Thanks alot and hope (most of) you understand.

Comment: Please do not say "for eg", ever. Only the [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) may say that.

Comment: "Sorting" isn't the right term, because you don't have a linear order on your elements. This is something more complicated.

Comment: Looks like "Longest path problem", which unfortunately is NP-complete.

Comment: @LivingThing So, did you gave try for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine every letter as a node in a graph. Each word represents a directed pathway between two letters in. "ACCA" defines A->A  "BAAC"  B-->C . Within this graph you would like to find a Eulerian Path. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path  . The Eulerian Path  is defined as a path that visits every edge exactly once and since each edge represents a word that means you have used all the words!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach may be to build a directed graph using the strings. There will be an edge from string `s1` to string `s2` if the last character of `s1` is the same as the first character of `s2`. Then you can try to find the longest path in the graph.